# Does $\forall a,b\in X: P(a,b)$ mean $\forall a\in X: \forall b\in X: P(a,b)$?

Tags: logic, soft-question, notation, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Sometimes I see expressions like $\forall a,b$ which is a quantifier followed by two variables. Does $\forall a,b\in X: P(a,b)$ mean $\forall a: \forall b\in X: P(a,b)$? So is $\forall a,b$ just an abbreviation?

In words: Is "for all a and b we have P(a,b)" just an abbreviation for "for all a: for all b: P(a,b)"?

Comment: Yes, the two are the same.

Comment: It can also be seen as an abbreviation of $\forall (a, b) \in X\times X:P(a, b)$. It's still the same thing.

Comment: The equivalence in the title is correct.  But in the question itself, you wrote $\forall a: \forall b\in X: P(a,b),$ which is *not* the same as $\forall a \color{red}{\in X}: \forall b\in X: P(a,b).$  The first sentence applies to *all* values of $a,$ whether in $X$ or not.  The second sentence, which makes a claim only about values for $a$ that happen to belong to $X,$ is the one equivalent to $\forall a,b\in X: P(a,b).$

Answer (score 1):

It just means "for any two elements of X, P is true about them."

I believe that what it reduces to in terms of the actual formal language grammar (or at least the one I use) is: $\forall x \ni (\exists y \ni (x\in X\land y\in X), P(x,y)),(\textrm{insert generic predicate here})$.

The problem is that it's less intuitive when written out in those terms, even though it ultimately means "given x and y in X, ( P(x,y) ) is true.

I would NOT recommend trying to think about it in terms of its official version, though. There's nothing to be gained in doing so; and the only thing lost is a ton of intuition, which is our guiding light as mathematicians.